# Efron-Stein inequality

Tags: probability

The Efron-Stein inequality sais that if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent random variables on say $R^n$, and $f:R^n \rightarrow R$ s.t. $Z:=f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ has finite variance, then

$$\operatorname{Var}(X)\le \sum_{i=1}^n E[(Z-E^{(i)}[Z]]$$

where $E^{(i)}$ denotes conditional expectation taken w.r.t. $X_i$ by keeping the rest of the variables fixed.

On going through the proof, it is not clear to me why do we need the variables to be independent and where is that used in the proof?

Answer (score 2):

You need the independence to get for all $i = 1,\cdots,n,$

$$E_i[E^{(i)}(Z)] = E_{i-1}(Z),$$

where $E_i$ is the expectation taken over $(X_1,\cdots,X_i)$ and $E^{(i)}$ is the conditional expectation on $(X_1,\cdots,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},\cdots,X_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E^{(i)}[Z]$ denote the conditional expectation $E[Z|X_1, \ldots, X_{i-1}, X_{i+1}, \ldots X_n]$.

At some point of the proof, we want to prove that $$E^{(i)}[(Z-E^{(i)}[Z])^2] = \tfrac{1}{2} E^{(i)}[(Z-Z_i^\prime)^2].$$ For this, we use a classical trick: if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d's then $\mbox{var}(X) = E[\tfrac{1}{2}(X-Y)^2]$.

Comment: But this comes later when expressing the r.h.s. of the bound in a different form by taking an independent copy of each $X_i$ variable. What I don't see is why the $X_1,...,X_n$ above need to be independent?

Comment: hello do you know how to prove that statement using the trick. im stuck at that part now.